# Circuitikz Current Label Placement

Tags: circuitikz

This is a follow-up question [on this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549629/circuitikz-current-error). In the aforementioned question, the current label `I_\textrm{G} = 0` is overlapping with a resistor, so I ask about current arrow and label placement.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}[declare function = {hypo = 4; x = 1; r ={1/2};}]
            \def\myeq{=}
            \ctikzset{label/align = straight}
            \draw({hypo*sqrt(2) + 2},0) to [battery , l_= $V_\textrm{in}$] ++({-hypo*sqrt(2) - 2},0);
            \draw(0,0) to[short, i = $I$] ++(0, -5) to[short, -*] ++(1, 0) node[label={below:$C$}](C){} to [R, l^= $R_1$, -*] ++(45:hypo) node[label={above:$A$}](A){} to[R, l^=$R_2$, -*] ++(-45:hypo) node[label = {below:$D$}](D){} to [short] ++(1, 0) to [short, i = $I$] ++(0,5);
            \draw(C) to[R, l_= $R_k$, -*] ++(-45:hypo) node[label = {below:$B$}](B){} to [R, l_=$R_x$] ++(45:hypo);
            %\draw(A) to [rmeter, t=G, i=$I_\textrm{G} \myeq 0$] (B);
            \draw(A) to[short] ++(0, {-hypo/sqrt(2) + 1}) coordinate (belowA);
            \draw(B) to[short] ++(0, {hypo/sqrt(2) - 1}) coordinate (aboveB);
            \draw(belowA) to [rmeter, t=G, i=$I_\textrm{G} \myeq 0$] (aboveB);
            \draw($(A) + (-x,0)$) -- ++(45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) coordinate(arcBeforeA);
            \draw(arcBeforeA) arc(135:45:r) node[pos = 0.5, label = {above:$I_A$}]{} coordinate(arcAfterA);
            \draw(arcAfterA) -- ++(-45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) node[currarrow, rotate=-45, anchor=tip]{};
            \draw($(B) + (-x,0)$) -- ++(-45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) coordinate(arcBeforeB);
            \draw(arcBeforeB) arc(-135:-45:r) node[pos = 0.5, label = {below:$I_B$}]{} coordinate(arcAfterB);
            \draw(arcAfterB) -- ++(45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) node[currarrow, rotate=45, anchor=tip]{};
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I found a rather ad-hoc way of placing the current arrow and label. Is there a way to draw the component `G` directly from node A to node B while able to control where the current arrow goes, like the command `node[pos = 0.4]` when placing the label? Usually, the current arrow and label are either halfway between starting point and component, or halfway between finishing point and component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dive into the code in `pgfcirccurrent.tex`. Below is the related code of currarrow.

```
    coordinate[currarrow,pos=\ctikzvalof{current/distance},rotate=\pgf@circ@ffffff,
    anchor=center](Iarrow)
    (Iarrow.\pgf@circ@bipole@current@label@where)
    node[anchor=\pgf@circ@dir, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole current style]
    (\ctikzvalof{bipole/name}current){\pgf@circ@finallabels{current/label}}
```

The pos of the currarrow is controled by `pos=\ctikzvalof{current/distance}`. So you can change the value of the key `.../current/distance` to change of pos of the arrow.

Circuitikz provides a command `\ctikzsetvalof` in `pgfcirc.defines.tex` to do such thing:

```
\def\ctikzsetvalof#1#2{\pgfkeyssetvalue{\circuitikzbasekey/#1}{#2}}
```

Then you can define a key:

```
\tikzset{
  cpos/.code={\ctikzsetvalof{current/distance}{#1}}
}
```

and write

```
\draw(A) to [rmeter, cpos=.2, t=G, i=$I_\textrm{G} \myeq 0$] (B);
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\tikzset{
  cpos/.code={\ctikzsetvalof{current/distance}{#1}}
}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}[declare function = {hypo = 4; x = 1; r ={1/2};}]
            \def\myeq{=}
            \ctikzset{label/align = straight}
            \draw({hypo*sqrt(2) + 2},0) to [battery , l_= $V_\textrm{in}$] ++({-hypo*sqrt(2) - 2},0);
            \draw(0,0) to[short, i = $I$] ++(0, -5) to[short, -*] ++(1, 0) node[label={below:$C$}](C){} to [R, l^= $R_1$, -*] ++(45:hypo) node[label={above:$A$}](A){} to[R, l^=$R_2$, -*] ++(-45:hypo) node[label = {below:$D$}](D){} to [short] ++(1, 0) to [short, i = $I$] ++(0,5);
            \draw(C) to[R, l_= $R_k$, -*] ++(-45:hypo) node[label = {below:$B$}](B){} to [R, l_=$R_x$] ++(45:hypo);
            \draw(A) to [rmeter, cpos=.2, t=G, i=$I_\textrm{G} \myeq 0$] (B);
            \draw($(A) + (-x,0)$) -- ++(45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) coordinate(arcBeforeA);
            \draw(arcBeforeA) arc(135:45:r) node[pos = 0.5, label = {above:$I_A$}]{} coordinate(arcAfterA);
            \draw(arcAfterA) -- ++(-45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) node[currarrow, rotate=-45, anchor=tip]{};
            \draw($(B) + (-x,0)$) -- ++(-45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) coordinate(arcBeforeB);
            \draw(arcBeforeB) arc(-135:-45:r) node[pos = 0.5, label = {below:$I_B$}]{} coordinate(arcAfterB);
            \draw(arcAfterB) -- ++(45:{x*sqrt(2) - r}) node[currarrow, rotate=45, anchor=tip]{};
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### ADD

Actually, there has been an example in the manual that shows how to change the position of the current, in `sec 4.6 Global properties of voltages and currents` of page 140
[image]